# Vue + Vuetify performance

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So I have a Vuetify data table with a lot of items, I need to display `50/100/150` items.

The problem, when I have 50 items it takes about 2 to 3 seconds to load the entire table. My request takes about 500ms to load and vue takes 3 seconds to render. When I have 150 items it takes about 10 seconds.

Is it possible to reduce render time to at least 5 seconds with 150 items?

I'm using this table: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-tables

My table code:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
    :items-per-page="50"
    :footer-props="rowsPerPageItems"
  >
    <TableRow :row="item" v-for="item in clientList" :key="item.id">
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

```js
// my clientList is async response from server
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      rowsPerPageItems: [50, 100, 150]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters["clientList"] // this comes from vuex, I don't think it's relevant. It returns about 400 client info
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- My component TableRow -->
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <v-checkbox v-model="row.checked" color="primary"></v-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>{{ row.data }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    <td>
    <!-- This is a jQuery plugin, I need it to keep track of every key pressed -->
      <Select2
        :id="row.id.toString()"
        :settings="{ minimumInputLength: 3, ajax: ajaxData, placeholder: labels.descriptionList[row.description] }"
        @select="handleSelect2($event)"
      />
    </td>
    <td v-if="this.is_expense">
      <v-select
        :items="labels.categoryName"
        :placeholder="labels.categoryList[row.category]"
        @input="updateCashflow"
        v-model="row.category"
        dense
      ></v-select>
    </td>
    <td v-else></td>
    <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening if you followed the docs correctly; I have used this table with larger datasets without this issue. My guess is that `TableRow` is your problem area, not Vuetify. Why are you binding different data to the table, than your `TableRow`? You also have 2 `items-per-page` set, which is confusing.

Comment: items-per-page is default setting to display when load, and rowsPerPageItems are the options. In the component case, i need it to be a component because I need to be able to access each row's data to change it I will update the component here, I forgot srry

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this stuff to access or modify your table data: [Content Editing](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#content-editing)

Comment: After your update, I can say with certainty that your `TableRow` component is the cause of your delays, not the `v-data-table`. You are tracking every key press, for every single row. Please read the docs for [Content Editing](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#content-editing), and for [CRUD Operations](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#crud-actions)

Comment: 3 seconds for render is way to much for 50 items, try to remove `TableRow` and test how much time it takes to load then. If it renders faster, then you have an answer - your TableRow isnt well built

Comment: it isn't, I tried clearing every component and data in side my TableRow and changed it to static string, and still takes a long time to render

Comment: if you think this could be the problem I'll try and optimize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I really need components inside my table so I used

```html
<v-select v-if="mountedComponent" :items="myList"/>
<span v-else>Some default value</span>
```

When page mounted I set mounted to true

```js
export default {
    name: "Test",
    data(){
        return {
            mountedComponent: false,
            myList:["item 1", "item 2"]
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.mountedComponent= true;
    }
}
```

This solved my performance issue, going from 10 ~ 15 seconds delay to 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that component and read `v-data-table` documentation.

1. You shouldn't add `v-checkbox` to make it rows selectable, use `show-select` prop instead with `v-model` on `v-data-table`
2. Use `item.<name>` slot to add custom components into cells

Comment: I didn't get your number 2

Comment: Do you know what is slots in Vue?
Basically you can add children element for `<v-data-table>` thats wrapped with `<template v-slot:item.[your-header-value-here]="{ item }">custom element {{item.id}}</template>`